# Problems with JSON and Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to send a request with the next code:

```
func getLogin(user: String, password: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.url.es/api/login")!

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "usuario" : "\(user)",
        "clave" : "\(password)"]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Basic TOKEN"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).validate()
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("repuesta")
            print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            print(response.response as Any) // URL response
            print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization

            debugPrint(response)
    }

}
```

But I am getting this response:

```
[Request]: https://www.url.es/api/login
[Response]: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000220b40> { URL: https://www.url.es/api/login } { status code: 401, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 28;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Mon, 16 Jan 2017 20:44:14 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    "Www-Authenticate" = Bearer;
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
[Data]: 28 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(401))
[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 506292395.911, "Initial Response Time": 506292396.351, "Request Completed Time": 506292396.352, "Serialization Completed Time": 506292396.353, "Latency": 0.440 secs, "Request Duration": 0.441 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.441 secs }
```

I am sending the request with paw http client and the response is ok.

I am working with swift3, alamofire 4 and iOS10

Answer (score 0):

According to the response you have there it looks like your username and password is incorrect. Try printing the parameters dictionary to make sure it is correct. Something that can happen sometimes is if you forget to unwrap an optional value it will still get sent. For example

```
let optionalString:String? = "blablabla"

print(optionalString) //prints: Optional(blablabla)
```

#### Edit:

Another thing I noticed is you set the encoding to JSON but the header Content Type is PlainText. Try setting the encoding to URLEncoding.default and make sure the headers are set appropriately for what the server is expecting.

Comment: If you replace the parameters definition to :                                                  let parameters: Parameters = [
            "usuario" : "aaa",
            "clave" : "bbb"]
The response is the same.

Comment: The parameters that I am including in the request is valid login parameters.

Comment: The problem is in the headers parameter. Without this parameter the request call is running.